# Excel SUMIF criteria within range of numbers

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I was wondering how to represent the criteria argument in the function =SUMIF(range, criteria) as instead of ">0" which represent greater than zero, which would add all numbers in the range that are greater than zero. I was wondering how to make it within the range of zero to 8, so "8>0", or something, but I have been googling for hours and cannot find a solution that doesn't involve doing whacky things with SUMIFS which involves other arrays which I do NOT want to get into because I feel there's a simple solution to this that I'm missing...
Theres ">=NUM" "<=NUM" ">NUM" and "<.NUM"
how do you make it require two of these?
Is there any documentation on this anywhere?
[image]

Comment: use `=SUMIFS` without some data I cant answer your question but look [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php)

Comment: I have been googling for hours and cannot find a solution that doesn't involve doing whacky things with SUMIFS which involves other arrays which I do NOT want to get into

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: sample data provided....

Comment: Cell with answer should be -28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @user3240704 that `SUMIFS` is the way to go.

If you insist on using `SUMIF` only then you can use the following logic:

- take the sum of the entire range
- deduct the sum of values <-10
- further deduct the sum of values >0

Which is the inverse of saying

- only the sum the values >=-10 and <=0

The formula is:

```
=SUM(A1:A11)-SUMIF(A1:A11,">0",A1:A11)-SUMIF(A1:A11,"<-10",A1:A11)
```

E.g.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for an answer that is related to the question.

Comment: But my real question was, why isn't there a criteria that checks for the value to be within a range of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

More info [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-between)

```
    =SUMIFS(A1:A11,A1:A11,">=-10",A1:A11,"<=0")
```

SUMIFS has many (in this case two) conditions, broken down as follows:

`=SUMIFS(A1:A11` - SUM() whatevers in A1:A11

,                - That match the following conditions

`A1:A11,">=-10"` - ALL numbers in A1:A11, that are greater than OR equal to -10

`,`              - AND

`A1:A11,"<=0"`   - ALL numbers in A1:A11, that are less than OR equal to 0

)

Comment: SUMIFS which involves other arrays which I do NOT want to get into because I feel there's a simple solution to this that I'm missing...

Comment: `SUMIFS` are not arrays, in fact [they can error if you try and use them with arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/192222).  If you wish to use arrays you should have said that in your question.

Comment: @tincopper2 I've added a breakdown of the `SUMIFS`, perhaps it gives you some insight into whats happening. MS documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/275165)